# parse error in /etc/sudoers.d

Tags: raspbian

Somehow I got the readme that is in/etc/sudoers.d without any permission other than read, so I can't sudo anything. I tried to change the permission with chmod o+rw readme but that didn't work. Is there any other way I can undo this change?

Comment: If this is the file you mean `-r--r----- 1 root root 958 2015-03-13 16:41 /etc/sudoers.d/README` then that is correct. What are you ACTUALLY trying to do?

Comment: show us the file?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to follow the same recipe that you would follow if you lost or forgot your password.  Here is a good article here:

http://www.mapledyne.com/ideas/2015/8/4/reset-lost-admin-password-for-raspberry-pi

Basically, if you follow that article, and reboot your PI, you will be in a root shell prompt.  From there you can edit your root protected files and undo the root shell start ... reboot again ... and all should be rosy in the garden.

Answer (score 2):

The `/etc/sudoer.d/` directory must have at least one file in it (the `README` file is just a suitable dummy one!) and they all must have that file permissions mask.  The bottom line is that that is probably NOT the reason why you could not get `sudo` to work three and a half years ago...

If anyone reads this then they should probably note that the `visudo` utility is ***the*** way to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file as it will go a long way to prevent a user from making a stupid mistake in the file that prevents `sudo` from working. As someone who always makes sure there is a valid `root` account on any *nix system they own - I can always log in as the superuser to fix things if they have gotten really fubar-ed.  However without that fall-back you are likely to have to find a way to edit that file in another machine as @Dmitry-Grigoryev suggests...

Answer (score 1):

Just take the micro SD card out of the Pi and fix the permissions in your sudoers folder on any Linux machine you have at hand which has working `sudo` or root access.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate the answer from *@SlySven* a bit, please read the `/etc/sudoers.d/README`. Here is the important part from it:

> Note that there must be at least one file in the sudoers.d directory (this one will do), and all files in this directory should be mode 0440.

So it is not a good idea to modify the permissions in any other way.